# How to calculate pitch and roll without magnetometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, magnetometer

In my app I am calculating azimuth, pitch and roll using accelerometer and magnetometer values:

```
        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];

        float[] inclinationMatrix = new float[9];

    private float[] mMagnetometerValue = new float[3]; //event.values
    private float[] mAccelerometerValue = new float[3]; //event.values

        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, inclinationMatrix, mAccelerometerValue, mMagnetometerValue);

        // Orientation.

        float[] orientation = new float[3];

        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientation);
```

Now orientation array returns azimuth, pitch and roll.
As documentation says [getOrientation function:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D))

values[0]: Azimuth, angle of rotation about the -z axis

values[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)): Pitch, angle of rotation about the x axis

values[2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/ed021eae5cc4ddb962ff7ee0eb875645671aa950/include/hardware/sensors.h#661): Roll, angle of rotation about the y axis.

Now good.
But testing in another phone failed, because this phone has only accelerometer, not magnetometer, nor gyroscope or rotation vector sensor. After debugging I found that phone has device orientation sensor. Only doc I am found is [this google gist.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/ed021eae5cc4ddb962ff7ee0eb875645671aa950/include/hardware/sensors.h#661)

Okay give a try. But this sensor returns only one float value, not float array.
So I can not pass this as parameter to SensorManager.getRotationMatrix function.

**Now question:
How to retrieve pitch and roll with SensorManager.getRotationMatrix and SensorManager.getOrientation or without this functions using accelerometer and this device orientation sensor.**

Comment: I suspect that the only way to get accelerometer information is via reflection on the system APIs but if the app is for the Play Store, restrictions may prevent. Also yaw, pitch and roll usually require a gyroscope to get the additional 3-axis with any accuracy.

Comment: Sure, but every compass app that I am downloaded on this phone works, so must be possibility using accelerometer with this sensor